# Regex to retrieve all the text in a line if a particular pattern matches

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regex to get all the contents of a line if there is a particular pattern match. The string that I want to search in a line is something like:

```
1. 7.2.S.6.4 ANNOTATED DATA 
    OR
2. 9-2-K-1-4 FILE DATA
    OR
3. 2-2.K-4.3 FOLDER DATA
```

From each of these cases I want to get as output:

1. ANNOTATED DATA
2. FILE DATA
3. FOLDER DATA

I want to write a regex to find out the first pattern example: '7.2.S.6.4' and then get the next words from the line after this pattern.

So far the regex that I have tried is

```
\s*(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

but it doesn't match the .S. or -K- part in the pattern. Any idea how to fix this

Comment: use this website to find the right regex https://regex101.com/

Comment: Try `re.sub(r'^\d+\.\s+\d+(?:[.-]\w+)*\s*', '', s)`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/44ZpvH/1)

Comment: if the data is as in the example you can just do:  `l=s.split(' ');  res=l[0] + l[2:]`

Comment: Why not just read line by line and test each line for a match separately? Less risk of catastrophic backtracking that way.

Answer (score 0):

Your use case is a bit cryptic to me, but this might work for the first match, tho it is not the most ideal solution:

```
\s*([-.]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?([-.][A-Z])?)[ ](.*)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex like this:

```
^(\d\.) \S+(.*)
```

And then grab content from capturing groups 1 and 2

**[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/N2oCOz/1)**

Also, you can use this regex, with `$1$2` as replacement string:

```
^(\d\.) \S+(.*)|.+
```

**[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/N2oCOz/2)**

Sample code

```
import re

regex = r"^(\d\.) \S+(.*)|.+"

test_str = ("1. 7.2.S.6.4 ANNOTATED DATA \n"
    "    OR\n"
    "2. 9-2-K-1-4 FILE DATA\n"
    "    OR\n"
    "3. 2-2.K-4.3 FOLDER DATA")

subst = "$1$2"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)
```

Answer (score 0):

These expressions might likely work here,

```
(?=[0-9]+[.-][0-9]+[.-][A-Z]+[.-][0-9]+[.-][0-9]+).*[0-9]\s(.+)
(?=[0-9]+[.-][0-9]+[.-][A-Z]+[.-][0-9]+[.-][0-9]+).*[0-9]\s+(.+)
```

This compartment makes sure that, we'd be having a right pattern

```
(?=[0-9]+[.-][0-9]+[.-][A-Z]+[.-][0-9]+[.-][0-9]+)
```

and here we'd capture our desired output

```
(.+)
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/NGrHFX/1/)

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/nrLio2/1/)

#### TEST

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(?=[0-9]+[.-][0-9]+[.-][A-Z]+[.-][0-9]+[.-][0-9]+).*[0-9]\s(.+)"

test_str = ("7.2.S.6.4 ANNOTATED DATA\n"
    "9-2-K-1-4 FILE DATA\n"
    "2-2.K-4.3 FOLDER DATA")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```